# How to simulate a click event in jQuery

Tags: jquery

note: all this is on chrome

I am trying to test something that responds to a click a checkbox. I realize jQuery.click() exists, but it seems to be different from a "native" click in that during the click handler, the state of the checkbox isn't updated yet (so checkbox is unchecked, you call .click(), in the handler, checkbox is still unchecked. If you actually click the box, in the handler the state is checked).

I apologize for the confusing question, here is a fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/XBhWy/

Click the foo button, notice that button handler says it has been checked, but the checkbox handler says it has not been checked (even though the ui shows a checkmark). Now, click the checkbox itself. Notice the click event handler is reporting what you would expect it to report.

My question is how to simulate the same thing that happens when you actually click the box.

Now, I took a stab at a better simulated event like this

```
$.fn.check = function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
  } else {
    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
  }
  $(this).click();
}
```

Unfortunately (and somewhat confusingly), it didn't work.

Anyone run into this before? Can it be accomplished?

Note that I'm not looking for the `click` method.

Comment: Have you tried http://api.jquery.com/click/?

Comment: because that doesn't work.....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that the user-specified function declared in the checkbox `click()` event fires BEFORE the checkbox is really updated. I played around with it and found that the `change()` listener acts as expected.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4emic/6xufL/1)

Comment: Change is a good idea, was banging my head against click for at least an hour before posting this. I wonder if anyone has a matrix of some kind talking about trigger limitations, would be extremely useful

Comment: The missing consistency for when the event fires is most likely a bug. I've filed a [bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10005) at the official jquery bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

from http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ :

> Although .trigger() simulates an event activation, complete with a synthesized event object, it does not perfectly replicate a naturally-occurring event.

So it is a known thing I guess. In this case it changes the order of some things.